# Scrolling does not work on webdriver.io on the web

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io, webautomation

I am not able to scroll down, using webdriver.io. Not getting any error messages, just not scrolling. I have tried different solutions from Webdrver.io docs:

```
it('should demonstrate the scroll command', function () {
    var elem = $('#myElement');
    // scroll to specific element
    elem.scroll();
    // scroll to specific element with offset
    // scroll offset will be added to elements position
    elem.scroll(100, 100);
    // scroll to specific x and y position
    browser.scroll(0, 250);
});
```

Non of them works, any suggestions?

Comment: You can try Actions class' move_to_element(element) to imitate scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create instance of Javascript executor

JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

//Identify the WebElement which will appear after scrolling down

WebElement e=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content-5']"));
je.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",e);
```

Comment: Its not for java. Title saying its Webdriver.IO which is JS framework

Answer (score 0):

I'm using v4 and browser.scroll() did not work for me either.

I instead used Actions -> [moveToObject](http://v4.webdriver.io/api/action/moveToObject.html) and it is successfully scrolling to the element.

Here is what my code looks like.

`browser.moveToObject('#id-of-my-element');`

Comment: Although a better solution would be to upgrade to v5!

Comment: what is the replacement of browser.moveToObject at new webdriveio. I wanna use that since scrollIntoView() not worked for my test

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `moveToElement()` method of `Actions` Class which moves the mouse to the specified element.

For Example:

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.name("Name"));

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

builder.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
```

You can also use `MoveToElement()` which moves the mouse to the specified offset of the top-left corner of the specified element.
Syntax: `MoveToElement(IWebElement, Int32, Int32);`

[Actions.htm](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Interactions_Actions.htm)